# Rails 4.2 doesn't update datetime fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord

I think I found a bug but I am not 100% sure if it is one or I am doing something wrong. I am setting up the timezone like this:

`inside application.rb`

```
...
config.i18n.default_locale = :en config.time_zone = 'Melbourne'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Melbourne'
...
```

When I am updating a model with timestamp columns (`created_at`, `updated_at`) it doesn't update them. The problem is caused by this line `config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Melbourne'` (when I remove it, it works fine). The query seems to be fine but when you reload the model the timestamps are nil. I think the problem appears in all the datetime columns and it doesn't matter which database you are using (I managed to reproduce it in postgres and in sqlite).

Is this something that I would expect because I forgot to configure something or is it a bug?

Comment: The docs say `active_record.default_timezone` should be either `:local` or `:utc`, not a timezone name.  This is choosing what's recorded in the database.  The `config.time_zone` setting determines what the UI presents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.active_record.default_timezone` accepts only two values:

- `:local`
- `:utc`

What you can do is set:

```
config.time_zone = 'Melbourne'
```

and then

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

will do the trick.